# Decimal degrees to meters in QGIS 3.03

Tags: qgis, distance, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I understand this question has been asked a few times but I am having trouble with this issue in QGIS 3.0.3.

These are the current CRS of my layers:

- Open Street Map (XYZ Tile) - EPSG: 3857 - WGS 84/Pseudo Mercator
- Addresses - EPSG: 4326 - WGS 84
- Road Data - EPSG: 4326 - WGS 84

I am trying to calculate distances using NNJoin tool from addresses to the road in the state of Missouri. I need my distance in meters but it only shows up in decimal degrees. I have enabled "on the fly" projection, changing CRS to a UTM zone (central Missouri), and making sure all the settings are presenting distances in meters (see image attached). Yet, I continuously get the warning that the measurement for the NNJoin tool will be in decimal degrees.

[image: QGIS Project Property page]

Comment: processing tools use the layer's CRS and metadata to perform analysis and measurements; the *on-the-fly* projection only affects the *map view* (and the GUI tools working on the current view). you will have to properly project those layers into a metric CRS (e.g. UTM).

Comment: Using UTM Zone 15s it still does not display distance in the metric system.